# The socket connection to localhost failed..ErrorCode: 10061

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock

When I type localhost on my browser , I am unable to successfully connect..I am getting

```
The socket connection to localhost failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You start a web server on your localhost listening on port 80. At present there isn't one.